# Testcafe differences between selectors ".exits" and ".visible"

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

Even tho` I have read the documentation that TC provides, I'm still not sure about what is the difference between:

```
await t.expect(element.visible).ok();
```

and

```
await t.expect(element.exists).ok();
```

*I have a hunch that somehow visible includes the exists check, but on the other side, and element could exist, but just not in the visible area...*

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.exists` only checks that element is in the DOM. It does not check for visibility.

If you want to check for visibility you have two ways:

```
await t.expect(element.with({visibilityCheck: true}).exists).ok();
await t.expect(element.visible).ok();
```

Comment: yes, this is what I'm also presuming. Therefore, in a small amount of scenarios (when i only want to check an element is inside the DOM) I can use exists, but instead, I could use visible for most of them, because somehow visible incorporated exists :)

Comment: It's not the same since in case of exists and count the selector is resolved immediately, while in case of visible it waits the whole selector timeout. Additionally you cannot overwrite it for exists and count. 
Source: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/element-selectors#selector-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Give a look here:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5368#issuecomment-668448192
and here
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements#selector-timeout

because there are differences in exist and visible execution, that will create you issues.